# Will TIME_TICK broadcast in deep sleep?

Tags: android

Does Android wake from deep sleep in order to broadcast `ACTION_TIME_TICK`?  From experimenting, I don't think it does, but I'm looking for a definitive answer.

My experiment involved registering a simple `BroadcastReceiver` to update a `TextView` on receive:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    int ctr = 0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        testView.setText("Time ticks: " + ++ctr);
    }
}, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
```

At 4 ticks, I turned off the screen for about 5 minutes, then turned it back on, and it read 6 ticks.  At 13 ticks, I turned the screen for 10 minutes, then turned it back on, and the number of ticks read 14.  It only seems to increase by 1-2 ticks no matter how long I leave the phone off, which is why I suspect it doesn't broadcast the action during deep sleep.

Comment: I'm experiencing what I suspect is the exact same problem. Have you found any solution/workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I looked into the Android code. No this broadcast will not wake up the phone. It uses an `AlarmManager.RTC` type `Alarm` to broadcast time change.

Why do you need to be notified literally every minute?

How about setting up your own Alarm using the `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` type?

**WARNING**: Doing it every minute is will drain your battery. I suggest doing it less often, like every hour.

Please let me know if this is helpful.

Emmanuel

Comment: I can't quite remember exactly how exactly I was going to use it (I abandoned work on that awhile ago), but the project involved doing more detailed uptime tracking than what is provided by the system.  Actually I think I preferred having it not do notifications when the phone was asleep, but just wanted some confirmation of this (since the API documentation is unclear on that point).

Comment: Using alarm manager works correctly. Thanks. I just wanted to know the cause of this behaviour. You found it.

Answer (score 3):

A better experiment: Instead of updating a `TextView` which you cannot see when the phone is off, write to the Log with:

```
Log.v("Tick","Total ticks: " + ++ctr);
```

You can keep an eye on this in Logcat while your phone is asleep.