# Android Connect to Running Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am creating an app that has a UIThread and a background thread.  The background thread is basically being used as a timer - every second it sends a message to the UIThread to update the UI.  When the user exits the app by hitting the backbutton, the thread continues to run.  I want this to happen since the user may want to open another app while the timer continues to count down.

My question is when the user comes back to my app.  I want to connect to that background thread that is running to display the current state of the app - how much time is left, etc.  My question is how to hook back in to the thread that is still running in the background.  I have tried using Thread and AsyncTask, but the same issue occurs.

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: If the UI isn't visible to the user, why are you updating it? If its so its fresh when the user returns, it at least makes sense to engage in exponential backoff of updates until the user returns, although I would argue, in the vast majority of cases this is wasted effort since any individual update should be so speedy anyway that the user won't mind waiting for it when he returns to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Your thread is still turning by sheer chance - your application is in fact still running but it and the thread will be shut down when Android decides it needs the resources.

However what you want to do is well-provided for in Android - you need to implement a Service to have a process that runs in the background separately from your application. You can even have a Service start at boot and run whether or not your application is started.

This http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html has most of what you need to know. To communicate between the Service and a foreground Activity you'll need to bind to a service interface, which is fortunately very easily done.

Comment: Or, still using Services, you can register a BroadcastReceiver in the Activity onResume, sending messages from the Service

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is to change your timer thread to a Service and have apps interested in it bind to that service.  Based on the Android documentation and suggested app design, you cannot depend on that thread to *not* be killed by the OS whenever it deems necessary.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Answer (score 0):

The android system provides a broadcast event every minute, it's call TIME_TICK.

You should:

- Create a service. This is the recommended way to have a part of the app running in the background
- Listen to the TIME_TICK event. This will consume less battery. ([It won't wake the phone, though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274583/will-time-tick-broadcast-in-deep-sleep), so use an ALARM, too)
- Add an alarm (to wake the phone if necessary)
- Let the UI and the service interact. You need a [callback via rpc](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) (see the last callback example on the api page)

You should also ensure that the phone can sleep during the timeframe. You thus may want to compute the state as a delta between the starting point and now, instead of updating the state all the time.

Comment: Oh please, do not do this. Why would you use TIME_TICK when you can use AlarmManager and set it for a time in the future? Also, please do not wake the phone every minute. In this case particularly, if the phone is waking to update a UI that the user CAN'T see, this is wasted work.

Comment: You read that time_tick wont wake your phone? Plus the UI may want to send a notification after countdown. In that case you'll have to wake the phone. Depending on the task of the activity you may want to wake the system from time to time and do some work, a common example is a network pull. A delta computation + an alarm might be the best solution, but it's hard to tell from the question.